# Enter key stopped working in ubuntu after updating gsettings

Tags: ubuntu, ascii, enter, gnome-terminal, gsettings

I was trying to setup my zsh to make different binding for enter and ctrl + enter, and faced the following problem.

Following instructions from [here](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019319) I executed these commands in the terminal:

```bash
gsettings set  org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"
gsettings set  org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name 'File Browser'
gsettings set  org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command 'nautilus'
gsettings set  org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding '<Enter>'
```

And after log-out and log-in my `enter` key has stopped to work at all. Now it works only in the sign-in screen. I've tried to revert the changes with the following command:

```bash
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
```

But it didn't help. Now when I open the terminal and type command `showkey -a`, after which I make the following sequence of key combinations: `enter`, `ctrl+enter`, `alt+enter`, the command emits the following text:

```bash
^[   27 0033 0x1b
^M   13 0015 0x0d
^[^M     27 0033 0x1b
     13 0015 0x0d
```

But earlier it generated the same symbol `^M` for all three. Please help me return to the default settings.

I've tried to revert the changes using `gsettings reset` command, I expected that my `enter` key will be boud to `^M` again, but it didn't help. Everything is the same.

Also tried:

```bash
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the file `$HOME/.XCompose`, which I configured to redefine `Ctrl + Enter` combination. Howerver, as it turns out, `ibus` doesn't support key modifiers (`Ctrl` in my case), and this file just reassigned `Enter`.

```bash
include "%L"
! Ctrl <Return> : "\037" # reassigns Enter instead of Ctrl+Enter
```